# confusion regarding find a solution for 2 Conic Section

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

Say we have a parabola $(y=(x-\frac{1}{4})^2 +a)$ where (a>0) and we also have a circle which passes through $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ and has radius of 2 units. We have to find such a value of a so that both these curves touch each other.
I started off with considering a circle $$(x-\frac{1}{4})^2 + (y-k)^2 = 4$$ as$ (\frac{1}{4},0)$ is mid pt of the 2 given points and circle's center should lie on this x=$\frac{1}{4}$ line on some $k>0$ also here I found k by substituting the point $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2},0)$
Here K comes out to be $(+ - \frac{\sqrt{63}}{4})$ I will take the +ve value as I am looking for a solution of https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v3holruats this kind 
now that I have k, I thought as these curves "touch" each other hence I can substitute $y-a$ as $(x-\frac{1}{4})^2$ in my equation of circle and put discriminant =0 as they will meet at a unique y
but on applying this I ended up with :-$$y^2 +(1-2k)y +k^2-a-4$$ now we know that ($K^2<4$) and $a>0$ hence$k^2-a-4$ becomes -ve hence how can I apply $b^2=4ac$ when $4ac<0$ 
why is this happening?, (I did this pictorially and i was easily able to find a=K+2 but why is this happening algebraically?)

Comment: "K comes out to be $(+-√63/4)"$

Comment: I am looking for this kind of soln: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v3holruats

Comment: @HaHa that's why I took k>0, nevertheless if k<0 then also we have a soln but i am not looking for that

Comment: @HaHa My apologies my mentality while solving the problem was inclined to finding a soln for k>0 you are absolutely correct in that corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a quartic system of equations. The resolving equation $$y^2 +(1-2k)y +k^2-a-4=0$$ turns out to be quadratic just because of symmetry (circle centre and vertex of parabola have the same abscissa).

If you look at your Desmos figure you'll see that for $a<k+2$ you have two intersection points, but those points have the same $y$ coordinate. It happens then that your resolving equation has two solutions, only one of them being acceptable up to $a=k+2$ (the other solution doesn't satisfy the constraint $y-a\ge0$). No way to apply the $\Delta=0$ trick in this case.